# error "Expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type int" in a loop when addressing a specific element in an array

Tags: c++

This function loops through the array and counts the amount of times that a card inside the array equals the target card and returns that value

```
int numOfCardInHand(const int array, int size, int targetCard) {
int Count = 0;
for (int card = 0; card < size; card++) {
    if (array[card] == targetCard) {
        Count += 1;
    }
return Count;
}
```

It gives me this error

"E0142 expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int""

and it is really throwing me for a loop `(pun intended)`

Comment: `array` is an `int`. You can't index an int.

Comment: Ahh I see now!                 const int array[]